# How can I know if I run emacs or aquamacs at the .emacs file?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to make different environment between Cocoa emacs and Aquamacs. They both read ~/.emacs, so I tried something like this.

```
(unless (symbolp 'aquamacs-version)
; code for emacs
)
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

How can I know if I run emacs or aquamacs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd try `(boundp 'aquamacs-version)`.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that what you're looking for is:

```
(when (featurep 'aquamacs)
   ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

`(symbolp 'aquamacs-version)` will always be true. `(boundp 'aquamacs-version)` will only be true if the symbol has been bound to ("assigned") a value. So your code can, essentially, be replaced by `(progn nil)`, as the condition is always true.

If `aquamacs-version` is a function, rather than a variable, use `(fboundp 'aquamacs-version)`.

Answer (score 2):

aquamacs will read .emacs, but you can put all your aquamacs specific customizations in aquamacs Preferences.el file:

> Install Aquamacs-specific preferences
>   and packages in Aquamacs Emacs paths,
>   others (which should be loaded by
>   other Carbon Emacsen) in Emacs paths.
>   Preferences (.emacs)
>
> These preferences are loaded, in the
>   given order:
>
> ~/.emacs  (deprecated -- meaning
>   'should not be used for new
>   installations, but will continue to be
>   supported' -- in Aquamacs on OS X) 
>   customizations saved by request or
>   automatically by Aquamacs in
>   customizations.el 
>   /Library/Preferences/Emacs/Preferences.el
>   /Library/Preferences/Aquamacs
>   Emacs/Preferences.el 
>   ~/Library/Preferences/Emacs/Preferences.el
>   ~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs
>   Emacs/Preferences.el

Comment: I need to use AucTeX for cocoa emacs, and I add -(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp")(load "auctex.el" nil t t) for it. As Aquamacs are pre equipped with AucTeX, I don't want Aquamacs run this code. That's the main reason why I need to check wether I run emacs or aquamacs.

Comment: why not try carbon emacs? it also has auctex by default, and is pretty much 'vanilla' emacs, plus a few packages. then you can just use (require 'auctex) in your .emacs. I don't think auctex even loads up until you enter latex mode either.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not in a position to test this, but if you can't identify Aquamacs by either `system-type` or `window-system`, then I imagine you could determine it from the command used to run it. Presuming the executable/link is in fact named "aquamacs", then I would think something like this should do the trick:

```
(unless (equal (car command-line-args) "aquamacs")
  ...)
```

Failing that, try `M-x apropos-value aquamacs RET` to search for any variables containing that string, to use in a similar comparison.